# iText7 add image in a paragraph in C#

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm totally new with iText7 and I'm trying to follow an old tutorial with C#; I want to put a text in a pdf document and under this text an image. Here's my code:

```
PdfWriter pdfwriter = new PdfWriter(DEST);
PdfDocument pdfdoc = new PdfDocument(pdfwriter);
Document doc = new Document(pdfdoc);

PdfFont myfont = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE);

// creates the img
ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create("C:\\Users\\dbu027\\Pictures\\postgresql fc6272.JPG");
Image image = new Image(imageData);

// creates a paragraph
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello!").SetFont(myfont);

p.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
p.SetPaddings(0,0,0,0);
p.SetMultipliedLeading(0);

// adds the image to the paragraph
p.Add(image);

// adds the paragraph to the doc
doc.Add(p);

doc.Close();
```

here's the result of my code:
[image]

here are my questions:
A) why it creates a space that occupies an entire page under the paragraph? why the image is put in a new page?

B) How can I check borders, paddings, margins, etc in a pdf? (e.g. like in chrome tools with HTML)?

C) How can i put a simple paragraph and just below the image?

Comment: By default itext adds an image at 72 pixels per inch. For any decent photo nowadays that means that it will fill a page and more. Use one of the `Image` methods `ScaleAbsolute`, `ScaleToFit`, and `Scale` to make it small enough for your intentions. And if you don't want the image to be part of the paragraph but follow thereafter, you probably should not add it to the paragraph but to the document right after adding the paragraph.

Comment: thanks! I also tried to add a new paragraph that contains the image, and i set SetMultipliedLeading to 1, it works!

Comment: If you've got it working, please create an actual answer here (instead of a mere comment) in which you can add a few details. After a short time (48 hours, I believe) you can also accept your own answer.